# My custom domain changes after I enter it to the replit basic domain

Tags: html

I just bought a domain for my website which I made in replit now I have like applied the domain to my website through Hostinger but the problem is like I have done it through by forwarding my replit project basic domain to my custom domain and now when I enter my custom domain and hit enter the website opens but the url changes to the basic replit domain which is ".knockbackiv.repl.co" but I wanted it to be ".shop" which I have bought.

I tried changing the nameservers but it also did not work

I expected the url to be "jaimalharagro.shop" when I enter "jaimalharagro.shop" but instead when I hit enter it changes to "jaimalharagro.knockbackiv.repl.co"

What I enter in URL
[image]

What result gives me after entering

[image]

Comment: https://docs.replit.com/hosting/custom-domains